# Updating neo4j relationship properties without duplicating the existing relationship

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I have the following to first create relationship between nodes (the nodes already created in a previous step)

```
MATCH (a:node), (b:node) WHERE a.name = 'sw1' AND b.name = 'sw2'
             merge (a)-[c:connect {packets_transmitted:0,packets_recieved:0}]->(b)
```

I need to update the properties without duplicating the relationship which is already exist. Now whenever I run the cypher, the relationship between the nodes **connect** duplicates. What should I do?

Here what I used for updating the relationship properties:

```
MATCH (a:node),(b:node) where a.name='sw1' and b.name ='sw2'
      merge (a)-[c:connect]->(b)
      set c.packets_transmitted = 250,c.packets_recieved = 300
```

**Update:**
This is the entire code  which I wrote in python (I modified it to be as clear as possible and still the relationship duplicates)

**Note:** The code works fine when I execute it directly in neo4j

```
cqlCreate_1=f"merge(n:node{{name:'openflow:2'}})"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_1)

cqlCreate_3=f"merge(m:node{{name:'2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'}})"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_3)

cqlCreate_2=f"MATCH (a:node),(b:node) WHERE a.name ='openflow:2'\
and b.name='2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'\
merge (a)-[c:connect{{p:0}}]-(b)"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_2)

cqlUpdate=f"MATCH (a:node)-[c:connect]-(b:node) where a.name='openflow:2'\
and b.name='2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'\
set c.p=200"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
    graphDB_Session.run(cqlUpdate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update with the code snippets, but I'm assuming you're using MERGE, not MATCH, in your update query, otherwise it would be completely impossible for duplicates to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:
No need to establish the relationship property when creating the relationship, since the whole code is executed every time and this leads to relationship duplication.  Below is the code after correcting it:

```
    cqlCreate_1=f"merge(n:node{{name:'openflow:2'}})"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_1)

cqlCreate_3=f"merge(m:node{{name:'2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'}})"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_3)

cqlCreate_2=f"MATCH (a:node),(b:node) WHERE a.name ='openflow:2'\
and b.name='2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'\
merge **(a)-[c:connect]-(b)**"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(cqlCreate_2)

cqlUpdate=f"MATCH (a:node)-[c:connect]-(b:node) where a.name='openflow:2'\
and b.name='2e:38:64:0e:e8:1f'\
set c.p=200"
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
    graphDB_Session.run(cqlUpdate)
```

Comment: I guess you were separating these for your tests, but now that you know that you shouldn't include the relationship properties in the pattern you can change this back to be a single query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a :connect relationship between the nodes (you don't care what the properties are to match upon) and then update the properties, then only MERGE the relationship, do not include the properties in the pattern. Then use SET to set the properties to the new values:

```
MATCH (a:node), (b:node) 
WHERE a.name = 'sw1' AND b.name = 'sw2'
MERGE (a)-[r:connect]-(b)
SET r.packets_transmitted = 0, r.packets_recieved = 0
```

If the properties should only be set on creation, then use ON CREATE SET instead.

EDIT: I removed the direction in the MERGE pattern, that will allow it to MERGE to an existing :connect relationship between the nodes, no matter the direction.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. The relationship still duplicates whenever I run the code. what should I do? note: I update the question to clarify. Thanks

Comment: In that case probably the relationship exists but in the opposite direction, from b to a instead of from a to b. If you don't care about the direction, you just want a :connect relationship between them, then omit the direction in your MERGE pattern: `MERGE (a)-[r:connect]-(b)`

Comment: I noticed that whenever the properties values change, a new relationship is created. how can I handle this so that only the properties values are updated without creating a new relationship?

Comment: I modified as you suggest and still, whenever I run the code, a new relationship is created :( . This is my last attempt and still duplicating `MATCH (a:node), (b:node) 
WHERE a.name = sw1 AND b.name = sw2
merge (a)-[:connect {packets_transmitted:50,packets_recieved:200}]->(b)`

Comment: From what you just pasted, you aren't using the approach in my solution. Do NOT include the properties in the merge pattern. Instead move them into the SET. And omit the direction of the relationship.

Comment: I do what exactly you wrote and still it duplicates the relationship. Is there any constraint that prevent creating a new relationship when the property value changes?

Comment: If it still zeros, no new relationship is created. BUT  if we change the values as follow, the relationship duplicates `MATCH (a:node), (b:node) 
WHERE a.name = sw1 AND b.name = sw2
MERGE (a)-[r:connect]-(b)
SET r.packets_transmitted = 200, r.packets_recieved = 300`

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? The planner should be locking both end nodes, there should be no way for a duplicate relationship to get created. You're sure the type is the same, no differences in case or whitespace? It may help if you add screenshots or results (and associated queries) that show the duplication, so we can rule out any misunderstandings. Also, for any perceived duplicates, please output or note the relationship id. If it's the same id, then it's the same relationship, not a duplicate. Also check node ids, maybe it's an issue of duplicate nodes.

Comment: As a test, what does this output? `MATCH (a:node), (b:node) 
WHERE a.name = 'sw1' AND b.name = 'sw2' RETURN count(*) as rowCount` and separately, what does this output, after removing duplicates? `MATCH (a:node)-[r:connect]-(b:node) 
WHERE a.name = 'sw1' AND b.name = 'sw2' RETURN id(a), id(b), count(r)`

Comment: I put the entire code in the question as Update. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In your query, you have a MERGE of the relationship, but the relationship includes a property. That's probably what's throwing you off. Remove that property from the pattern, set the property in a SET *after* the MERGE.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. And It works. I put the corrected code as an answer. Thanks for helping me